# javascript || (or) condition has better performance or includes?

Tags: javascript, performance

which one has better performance and why ? thank you for helping me

```
if(x==="abc" || x ==="def" || x==="ghi" || x==="jkl"){
 //logic
}

if(["abc","def","ghi","jkl"].includes(x)){
 //logic
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know the use case where it matters.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You could add switch-case in there too :)

Comment: @Rod911 and a Set, and a Map, and an object, etc. I don't think that really matters, *my* questions would be 1. Is this really a bottleneck? 2. Does performance even matter? 3. If this *really* is a bottleneck and it's a huge enough performance problem, can I see the code where an `if` statement is the only non-performant piece of code?

Comment: The only way to know the performance of something is to benchmark it. And which is faster in one situation likely isn't in another.

Comment: Probably more important: It almost never actually matters. Don't waste time on premature optimizations like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference on small array
Maybe it does a difference on a bigger array

```js
var loop = 1000000;

var total1 = 0;


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


for(var i = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
    var x = ["abc","def","ghi","jkl", "aze", ][getRandomInt(0,3)];
    var a = new Date().getTime();
    if(x==="abc" || x ==="def" || x==="ghi" || x==="jkl"){
     var b = new Date().getTime();
     total1 += (b-a);
    }
    else {
         var b = new Date().getTime();
     total1 += (b-a);
    }
}



var total2 = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
    var x = ["abc","def","ghi","jkl"][getRandomInt(0,3)]
    var a = new Date().getTime();
    if(["abc","def","ghi","jkl"].includes(x)){
     var b = new Date().getTime();
     total2 += (b-a);
    }
    else{
      var b = new Date().getTime();
      total2 += (b-a);
   }
}


console.log("=> total1 "+(total1/loop));
console.log("=> total2 "+(total2/loop));
```